# Interpretation of Notation $[k,k)$

Tags: real-analysis, word-problem

I'm trying to understand a prove and struggling with the following introduction of a Notation:

"Furthermore, let us introduce the notation $[k,l)  = \{k,k+1,\dots,l-1\}$", with the numbers taken modulo $n$, and no number occurring more than once. In particular, $[k,k) = \mathbb{Z}/(n)$ for every $k$."

If I choose $n=4$, then $[2,7) = \{0,1,2,3\}$ and $[2,4) = \{2,3\}$. But why is $[3,3) = \mathbb{Z}/(4) = \{ 0,1,2,3 \}$?

(Source: https://books.google.de/books?id=ButlynVk25MC&pg=PR7&lpg=PR7#v=onepage&q&f=false – Problem 7: African Rally)

Comment: I never came across this notation. $\mathbb Z/(n)$ is isomorphic to the $n$th root of unity in $\mathbb C$ via $f: k \mapsto e^{2ik\pi/n}$, so here is a way to make sense of the notation: start at $f(k)$ and walk along the circle until you reach $f(l)$. $[k,l)$ is the set of all roots of unity you came through during that walk except f(l).  For $[k,k)$, you obtain all of $\mathbb Z/(n)$ since you did a complete turn around the circle.

Comment: OK, I've only come across the Notation $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ as the modulo factor ring. But even with the definition as the $n$-th root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$, it's not clear to me why $[k,k) \neq \{k \mod n\}$, as you could not move an still reach $f(k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taladris's comment is a good explanation, but to perhaps make things more obvious: if we let $k=4$ we have $[4,4)$ as the notation, which we understand expands to $[4,3]\mod 4$.  However, we're *also* working modulo $4$, so applying the standard notation that $4 \equiv 0 \mod 4$ we now have $[0,3]$.  So this yields the set $\{0,1,2,3\}$ as required.

You note in your own comment that you're starting at a point and could not move and still reach that point.  Well yes, but actually you're not trying to reach the point you start from, you're trying to reach the point immediately "behind" it (speaking rather loosely) without being allowed to move backwards.

Comment: Thank you very much. I now do understand the explanation with the circle and movement only being allowed in one direction. My problem with the more formal explanation is, that it works for $k=4$ ($[4,4) = [4,3] \equiv [0,3] = \mathbb{Z}/(4)$) but for other values, e.g. $k=2$ it doesn't ($[2,2) = [2,1]$).

Comment: But $[2,1]=[0,1]=\{0,1\}$, so that does work, doesn't it?

Comment: That's true, iff $n=2$, but if $n$ still equals $4$ (so $k \neq n$) you cannot transform the interval (at least I think so)

Comment: So the interval *notation* $[k,l)$ is just a shorthand for the set of numbers between $k$ and $l-1$ (inclusive) taken modulo $n$.  So for $n=2$ you must end up with one of $\{0\}, \{1\}$ or $\{0,1\}$ as the final set, which you can represent as $[0,0], [1,1]$ and $[0,1]$ respectively.  So you can always transform the interval.  It may get smaller however: $[4,2)$ when $n=4$ will becomes $[0,1]$.